# How to store multiple cart items into database Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have question. how to store multiple cart items into database ?

this is my model :

```
$id_order = $this->db->insert_id();

$data_order = array();
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item => $val)
            {
              $data_order[] = array(
                  'idorder' => $id_order,
                  'iditem' => $val['id_activity'][$item],
                  'idtar'   => $val['id_price'][$item],
                  'timeslot' => $val['hour'][$item],
                  'itemquant' =>  $val['qty'][$item]
              );
            } 
$this->db->insert_batch('di420_ordersitems', $data_order);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is "$id_order"?

Comment: yes, i getting an errors,  A non well formed numeric value encountered.

id_order is the last inserting id to another table. $id_order = $this->db->insert_id();